# How to split the tweets into indivisual columns, like Teehanlax.com?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how teehanlax.com got to display their individual tweets in a separate columns. I've been looking at the website and it seems as if they are using a modified version of http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ which I was able to find their script here http://www.teehanlax.com/wp-content/themes/teehan-lax/resources/js/jquery.tweet.js I noticed that they are using Wordpress as their framework but I don't think it has any baring on the script. The twitter is being called into A div tag under tweet class, which is apparent in the original script (if it really is a modified version of it). It seems as if the jQuery script splits the tweets into paragraph tags and then in the css you can control those tags but I haven't been able to figure out how I could implement this myself or if I even could.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Marc180

Comment: Do you want to load them with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the plugin, it's the css that places the tweets in "columns". Basically the idea is the have tweets floated to left, with margin as a gutter. Like this:

```
.containter {
    width:640px;
    margin-left:-20px; /* -gutter with */
    overflow:hidden /* to clear floats  */
}
.tweet {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:20px; /* gutter */
}
```